# Custom QDockWidget display

Tags: c++, python, qt, pyqt, qt-designer

How would you get a display of dockwidgets/centralwidget in which the dockwidget in the `Qt::BottomDockWidgetArea` or `Qt::TopDockWidgetArea` doesn't take `Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea` nor `Qt::RighDockWidgetArea` space?

This is the actual display, with 2 dockwidgets and the central widget at the top right:

[image: dockwidget display actual]

This would be the preferred display:

[image: dockwidget display preferred]

Comment: Does the order of adding them to the `QMainWindow` make a difference?

Comment: @cmannett85 no, it makes no difference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you probably should use the [QMainWindow](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html)'s corner functionality to get the behavior you wanted.

Something like this may work (can't test whether its compiles, sorry):

```
mainWindow->setCorner(Qt::TopLeftCorner, Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea);
mainWindow->setCorner(Qt::TopRightCorner, Qt::RightDockWidgetArea);
mainWindow->setCorner(Qt::BottomLeftCorner, Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea);
mainWindow->setCorner(Qt::BottomRightCorner, Qt::RightDockWidgetArea);
```

See:
* [QMainWindow::setCorner(...)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#setCorner)

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the (slightly bizarre) trick to get this working is to set a QMainWindow as the central widget of your main window.

Here's a PyQt port of this [Qt FAQ example](https://wiki.qt.io/Technical_FAQ#Is_it_possible_for_either_the_left_or_right_dock_areas_to_have_full_height_of_their_side_rather_than_having_the_bottom_take_the_full_width.3F):

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Extended Side Dock Areas')
        self.window = QtGui.QMainWindow(self)
        self.window.setCentralWidget(QtGui.QTextEdit(self.window))
        self.window.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Widget)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.window)
        self.dock1 = QtGui.QDockWidget(self.window)
        self.dock1.setWidget(QtGui.QTextEdit(self.dock1))
        self.window.addDockWidget(
            QtCore.Qt.BottomDockWidgetArea, self.dock1)
        self.dock2 = QtGui.QDockWidget(self)
        self.dock2.setAllowedAreas(
            QtCore.Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea | QtCore.Qt.RightDockWidgetArea)
        self.dock2.setWidget(QtGui.QLabel('Left Dock Area', self.dock2))
        self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, self.dock2)
        self.dock3 = QtGui.QDockWidget(self)
        self.dock3.setWidget(QtGui.QLabel('Right Dock Area', self.dock3))
        self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, self.dock3)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```