# Qt DockWidgets distribution

Tags: c++, qt, qdockwidget

I'm working in a QT Application with dock widgets. But I can't do the desired distribution, my current distribution is this:

[image]

But i want this other distribution:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: include your code pls

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom QDockWidget display](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332832/custom-qdockwidget-display)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the corner on QMainWindow.

```
setCorner(Qt::Corner::BottomRightCorner, Qt::DockWidgetArea::RightDockWidgetArea);
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#setCorner